# How to add a mouse listener while in a for loop

Tags: java

So I am having a problem where I cant get out of a drawing for loop, i believe its because the MouseListener isnt working in the for loop, i was wondering if there was a way to add the Mouse listener to work while in the for loop so I can check when the Mouse is released. 
This is for a school project, and i am new to Java so a simple explanation would be best. Thanks

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.MouseHandler;
public class main extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    int x,y;
    static int time = 0;
    static boolean mousePressed;
    static JFrame f = new JFrame("TEST");

    static JPanel p = new JPanel();
    static JLabel l = new JLabel("Hello");

    public main() {
        p.addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        //g.drawLine(10, 10, 200, 300);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        p.add(l);
        f.add(p);


        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.getContentPane().add(new main());
        f.setResizable(false);

        f.setVisible(true);


    }


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {





            x=(int) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
            y=(int) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY()-46;
            if(mousePressed = true) {
             Graphics g = getGraphics();
             g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
             try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
             mouseClicked(e);
             mousePressed = false;
            }
            else
                mousePressed=true;



    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePressed=true;
        mouseClicked(e);

    }








    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mousePressed=false;
        System.out.println("TEST");
        mouseClicked(e);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }            
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }


}
```

Comment: I can't see a `for`  loop, or indeed any drawing code.

Answer (score 1):

> ... *MouseListener isnt working in the for loop*

1. There is no `for` loop in your application.
2. `mouseClicked(e);` inside `mouseClicked` is calling itself infinitely.
3. You shouldn't draw while inside a mouse listener, instead modify the state and then invoke `repaint()`.
4. If you implement `paint()` yourself, you should paint the entire window, not just what you want added to the window. Or delegate to the parent class' `paint()`.

For example:

```
public class Test extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    int x, y;
    boolean mousePressed;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }
    public Test() {
        super("Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g); // paints the entire window normally
        if (mousePressed) { // additional painting
            g.drawLine(x - 20, y, x + 20, y);
            g.drawLine(x, y - 20, x, y + 20);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        mousePressed = true;
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePressed = false;
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```